# How to make original (0,0) coordinate to be on the top left of QGLWIdget?

Tags: qt, opengl, qglwidget

I want to display an image using QGLWidget,  it doesn't show in the correct way, one of the problems is the original coordinate is on the bottom left of the widget.
I would like to know how to make the original coordinate to be on the top left and flip the y axis.

[image]

here's my code:

header

```
#ifndef _GLImageDisplay_H_
#define _GLImageDisplay_H_

#include "stdafx.h"

class GLImageDisplay : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLImageDisplay(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void DisplayImage(QString img);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

private:
    QImage svgImage;
    GLubyte* gluImage;
};

#endif
```

cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GLImageDisplay.h"

GLImageDisplay::GLImageDisplay(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget (parent) 
{
}

void GLImageDisplay::DisplayImage(QString img)
{
    svgImage.load(img);
    resize(svgImage.size());

    gluImage = new GLubyte[svgImage.height() * svgImage.width() * 3];
    for (int a = 0; a < svgImage.width(); ++a)  
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < svgImage.height(); ++b) 
        {
            QColor color = svgImage.pixel(a, b);
            gluImage[3 * (a + b * svgImage.width()) + 0] = (GLubyte) color.red();
            gluImage[3 * (a + b * svgImage.width()) + 1] = (GLubyte) color.green();
            gluImage[3 * (a + b * svgImage.width()) + 2] = (GLubyte) color.blue();
        }
    }

    this->setMinimumWidth(svgImage.width());
    this->setMinimumHeight(svgImage.height());
}

void GLImageDisplay::initializeGL() 
{
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
}

void GLImageDisplay::resizeGL(int w, int h) 
{
    glViewport(0, 0, svgImage.width(), svgImage.height());

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, svgImage.width(), 0, svgImage.height(), 0, 1);   
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void GLImageDisplay::paintGL() 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
    glDrawPixels(svgImage.width(), svgImage.height(), GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gluImage);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL coordinates start at the bottom. To fix this, you can do a -1 scaling in the y axis in your projection matrix. The offset is related.

To fix this, alter your call to `glOrtho` or apply a scaling + translation just after the call.

Btw. you could also use `QPainter` and use `beginNativePainting()` wherever you really need GL. `QPainter` will already use GL itself and perform *very* well.

`glDrawPixels` is a *very* inefficient way of drawing an image onto screen. You should rather load it into a texture and draw a quad with it. (Yet again, `QPainter` can do that for you, too, much more easily.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [ypnos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21974/ypnos)!

in the end i flip the projection matrix gluOrtho2D(0, width, height, 0);
and flip the text coord.

here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GLImageDisplay.h"

GLImageDisplay::GLImageDisplay(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget (parent) 
{
}

void GLImageDisplay::DisplayImage(QString img)
{
    myImage.load(img);

    // calculating power-of-two (pow) size
    int xpow = (int) std::pow(2.0, std::ceil(  std::log10((double)myImage.width())/std::log10(2.0)  )   );
    int ypow = (int) std::pow(2.0, std::ceil(  std::log10((double)myImage.height())/std::log10(2.0)  )   );

    // the texture should be square too
    xpow = std::max(xpow, ypow);
    ypow = xpow;

    // shrink if the size is too big
    if(xpow > 1024) 
    {
        xpow = 1024;
        ypow = 1024;
    }

    // transform the image to square pow size
    scaledImage = myImage.scaled(xpow, ypow, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
    glImage = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(scaledImage);

    this->setMinimumWidth(myImage.width());
    this->setMinimumHeight(myImage.height());

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &imageID);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, imageID );
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, scaledImage.width(), scaledImage.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glImage.bits());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void GLImageDisplay::initializeGL() 
{
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}

void GLImageDisplay::resizeGL(int width, int height) 
{   
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, width, height, 0);    // flip the y axis
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void GLImageDisplay::paintGL() 
{
    int width = myImage.width();
    int height = myImage.height();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(10,10);
    glVertex2f(10,600);
    glVertex2f(300,10);
    glEnd();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, imageID );
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, glImage.width(), glImage.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glImage.bits());

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    // text coord is flipped
    glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex3d(0,     0,      0);
    glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex3d(width, 0,      0);
    glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex3d(width, height, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex3d(0,     height, 0);

    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

but i'm encountering another issue when i try to display a large image where the bottom of the widget is cut and displays black area. It seems that the widget only is rendered at most the height of my LCD screen (?) I'm wondering QGLWidget can't be easily put in the QScrollArea (?). It's a different issue though.

[image]

Comment: To solve this problem, you should switch to QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView setup. You can use GL when you set the target to the QGraphicsView to a QGLWidget. There is example code available here: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/modelviewer  It is very powerful, although a little bit complicated I have to admit. Otherwise you would need to do whole GL redrawing when scrolling, or render to an FBO (QGLBuffer) and display that one accordingly in scrolled region.

Comment: Note that in the modelviewer example they let the QGraphicsScene always be the size of the QGraphicsView to avoid scrolling. Instead you would just set the QGraphicsScene dimensions to the ones of your image/content.

Comment: I'll take a look that modelviewer. People recommend to subclass qabstractscrollarea with qglwidget and set the viewport position with scrollbar positions. Do you think this'll work, i'm still trying to implement it.

Comment: Yes I think it can work. The difference here is that if you scroll in the QGraphicsView, the scene will not need to be redrawn, as I believe it draws into a framebuffer (texture) and will only blit the framebuffer again when scrolling. At least that's what it is doing for embedded widgets.